# factorization into disjoint r-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

This is question 8.26 from Dan Saracino's abstract algebra.
I have showed that, for every $h \in S_n$, $h \circ (x_1,...,x_r) \circ h^{-1} = (h(x_1),...,h(x_r))$.

But part b) is as follows,
[image]

I tried doing the only if direction. My attempt : Suppose $f_1 = f_{n_1} \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ f_{n_r}$ and $f_2 = g_{n_1} \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ g_{n_r}$, where f, g are disjoint.

Then I defined $h = \begin{pmatrix}
f_{n_1} & ... & f_{n_r}\\
g_{n_1} & ... & g_{n_r}
\end{pmatrix}$, so $h \circ f_1 \circ h^{-1} = g_{n_1} \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ g_{n_r} = f_2$

But for the other direction I am stuck.

Please correct me if my attempt is wrong, I need some help thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if part is much easier.

$f_2=h \circ f_1 \circ h^{-1}$

$ = 
h \circ f_{n_1} \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ f_{n_r} \circ h^{-1}$

$ = h \circ f_{n_1} \circ h^{-1} \circ h\circ f_{n_2} \circ h^{-1} \circ h \circ f_{n_3} \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ f_{n_r} \circ h^{-1}$

$=g_{n_1} \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ g_{n_r}$,

where  $g_{n_i}=h \circ f_{n_i} \circ h^{-1}$. Hence $g_{n_i}$ and $f_{n_i}$ have same length. So $f_1$ and $f_2$ have same number of r-cycles for every r.